# Gerar xml automaticamente

Tags: php, xml

Quero que depois de ler a página html com o *`file_get_contents`* e selecionar o que interessa com o `preg_match_all` a seja automaticamente gerado o xml (chamando a função abaixo) e gerando o arquivo.

Como são várias listas a serem geradas no mesmo php, não queria ter que repetir os comandos do `XmlWriter`, só chamar a função pra fazer automaticamente.

```
<?php

header ('Content-Type:application/xml');
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.teste.com/');
$re = '/href=\'(.*?)\'>(.*?)</(.*?)';
preg_match_all($re, $html, $key);
foreach($key[1] as $i)  

function lista_xml($xml){   
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openMemory();
    $xml->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $xml->startElement('items');
    $xml->startElement('lista');
    $xml->writeCData('$nome');
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->startElement('canal');
    $xml->startElement('titulo');
    $xml->writeCData('.$key[2][$i].');
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->startElement('img');
    $xml->writeCData();
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->startElement('link');
    $xml->writeCData('.$key[1][$i].');
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->startElement('detalhes');
    $xml->writeCData('<center><img src='".$key[3][$i]."'/> '.$key[2][$i].'</center>');
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();
    echo $xml ->outputMemory();
    $xml->flush();
    unset($xml);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro que teu foreach não tá fazendo nada e segundo que o `lista_xml` nunca é chamado, seu código não faz nada simplesmente, agora os problemas **graves**, aspas simples não interpretam variáveis:

```
$xml->writeCData('$nome');
```

Isso vai tentar gerar uma tag literalmente nomeada de `$nome` e não com o valor.

Você abriu aspas como se estivesse concatenando, mas não tem sentido:

```
$xml->writeCData('.$key[1][$i].');
```

Isso vai escrever uma tag assim:

```
<foo><!CDATA[[$key[1][$i]]]></foo>
```

Ao invés do conteudo vai escrever literalmente `<!CDATA[[$key[1][$i]]]>`

Tua regex também esta errada:

```
 $re = '/href=\'(.*?)\'>(.*?)</(.*?)';
```

No PCRE tem que que sempre haver os delimitadores https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php, no caso é possivel que tenha sido um erro de digitação e você esqueceu o `/` no final e de escapar o `/` depois de `<` (seria melhor usar outro delimitador), revisado e removido o que é desnecessário:

```
 $re = '#href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]>(.*?)</(.*?)#';
```

> nota: troquei ele por `['"]` porque assim pegará links que tenham `href="..."` e `href='...'`
>
> não queria ter que repetir os comandos do XmlWriter, só chamar a função pra fazer automaticamente.

Sim, basta criar um arquivo e função, deve ficar assim:

**gerarxml.php**

```
<?php

function GerarXml($nome, $re, $html)
{
    header ('Content-Type:application/xml');
    preg_match_all($re, $html, $data);

    //Inicia o XML
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openMemory();
    $xml->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
    $xml->startElement('items');

    foreach ($data[1] as $key => $value) {

        $xml->startElement('lista');
        $xml->writeCData($nome);
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement('canal');

        $xml->startElement('titulo');
        $xml->writeCData($data[2][$key]);
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement('img');
        $xml->writeCData('algo aqui');
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement('link');
        $xml->writeCData($data[1][$key]);
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->startElement('detalhes');
        $xml->writeCData('<center><img src="'.$data[3][$key].'"/> '.$data[2][$key].'</center>');
        $xml->endElement();

        $xml->endElement(); //Finaliza canal
    }

    //Finaliza o </items>
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->endDocument();
    echo $xml->outputMemory();
    $xml->flush();
}
```

Para executar chame assim:

```
<?php

require_once 'gerarxml.php';

GerarXml('teste', '#href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"]>(.*?)</(.*?)#', file_get_contents('http://seusite.com/'));
```

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pela ajuda. Testei e apresentou erro na linha 33. Naturalmente por conta das aspas. Sem as aspas duplas "error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document".

Comment: testei várias vezes mas sem sucesso. Cheguei a usar a um texto html direto sem usar  o file_get_contents e o resultado continua sendo uma página vazia. Não queria ter que usar uma classe externa para o XML. E entre os nativos acho que o XmlWriter é o mais adequado.

Comment: Sim, Guilherme. Testei em 4 servidores diferentes. Num Mac (localhost) PHP 7.1, num NAS (PHP 5.4), num servidor gratuito e no xamp (Windows). Todos com o display_errors on. Devo estar fazendo algo errado, certamente. A mensagem de erro: (This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document)

Comment: @AntonioOliveira corrigi o script, copie novamente, se o mesmo erro ocorrer remova esta linha `header ('Content-Type:application/xml');` e salve o script, então aperte F5 no navegador irá aparecer todos os erros.

Comment: Oi, Guilherme. Agora funcionou sim. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @AntonioOliveira então marca a resposta com correta por favor, se não souber como fazer leia isto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Comment: Só faltou um detalhe: Como seria o código se a parte de gerar o xml fosse uma função (desde o "//Inicia o XML"), para evitar ter que repetir todos os comandos de inclusão de células? Num site de notícias, por exemplo, teria que gerar 7 tabelas xml, o que tornaria o código bem longo.

Comment: @AntonioOliveira mas vc quer gerar 7 xmls diferentes na mesma requisição? Creio que isto não seja possivel

Comment: Não. As requisições serão diferente. O primeiro xml encaminhará para uma segunda página e aí por diante. Será um regex diferente e, naturalmente outra requisição.

Comment: Oi, Guilherme. A função ficou perfeita. Justamente o que eu precisava. Obrigado.

Comment: A função ficou perfeita. Mas gostaria de tirar outra dúvida. Como faço para armazenar na memória `'titulo'` `'img'` e `'link'` ? Para que na na segunda tabela possa usar:  `GerarXml('titulo', '#o regex da página secundária#', file_get_contents('link'));` ?? como esses elementos são dinamicamente gerados na função que vc criou, com o  `foreach ($data[1] as $key => $value)`, na segunda requisição esses dados também precisam ser variáveis.