# Ajuda com o $GET[id]

Tags: php

Considerando o php abaixo:

```
<?php
require_once 'gerarxml.php';
/*O gerarxml.php foi uma valiosa contribuição do amigo Guilherme Nascimento:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240387/gerar-xml-automaticamente/240392?noredirect=1#comment496556_240392 */

$id=$_GET['id'];
if($id==1){

//Categorias
GerarXml('IG', '#href="(?P<link>.*?ig\.com\.br\/)" title="(?P<title>.*?)">#', file_get_contents('http://ig.com.br'),); // nome do site, regex, file_get_contents
} // A sugestão de usar (?P<link>.*?), em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242663/php-file-get-contents-follow-url/242671?noredirect=1#comment497755_242671, dada pelo amigo FernandoVR, foi importante para dar robustez a função gerarxml.php (porque não importa a ordem dos elementos)

//Subcategorias
else if($id==2)
GerarXml('IG', '#href="(?P<link>.*?)" title="(?P<title>.*?)".*image" src=(?P<logo>.*?)"#', file_get_contents('o que vai aqui??'),); // nome do site, regex, file_get_contents
// aqui também há a questão das páginas seguintes (aceito sugestões)

else if($id==3){
GerarXml('IG',re, file_get_contents('o que vai aqui??');
}
?>
```

Preciso capturar 3 elementos variáveis da id1 para usar na id2 e idem da id2 para a id3 (`$title`, `$logo` (quando existir) e `$link`)
    Ou seja: id1=>id2=>id3 (id1 página inicial, id2 desdobramento da id1 e, id3 desdobramento da id2)

Um complicador, creio eu, é que esses elementos (title, logo e url) são gerados na função `gerarxml.php` usando o `preg_match_all` e `foreach` (`$data[1] as $key => $value`)(vinculada com `require_once`)
No id1 eu defino literalmente a url para o `file_get_contents` 'http://ig.com.br'; mas na id2 e id3 preciso usar a variável `$url`;

Testei com um outro esquema (sem usar `require_once`) e usando `$id2=$url`. Mas a id2 só capturou o conteúdo da página inicial (não seguiu para seu respectivo desdobramento), além de capturar conteúdo igual para todas as categorias (id1)

Comment: coloca isso dentro de um array e faz um teste para ver o que vai ser retornado, e faz auto incremento do seu ID assim o indice do id 2 ele capturará o indice do id1 e o do 3 pega o id2

Comment: Desculpa pela ignorância de iniciante, mas poderia mostrar concretamente como fazer?